# Is there any way to set the height of an imageview relative to the screen height

Tags: java, android, xml

The layout_weight tag helped to set the width relative to width.
Is there anything like that for adjusting height?
Am a beginner pls help me. :)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:paddingTop="0dip" android:layout_gravity="top"
   >
   <LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:paddingBottom="5dp"
   android:paddingLeft="10dp"
   android:paddingTop="5dp"
   >
   <ImageView
   android:id="@+id/image"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_weight="1"
   android:layout_gravity="left|top"
   android:scaleType="centerCrop"
   android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
   <ImageView
   android:id="@+id/imaget"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_gravity="left|top"
   android:layout_weight="1"
   android:scaleType="centerCrop"
   android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>
    </TableLayout>
```

Comment: just set the height to match_parent, both Image views will be equal

Comment: what should i do if want 3x2 layout

Comment: the view that should be bigger, set to weight=0.25, the smaller one to weight=0.75

Comment: no @Opiatefuchs i mean i have to display 6 images at a time in a screen.
(like 3X2 matrix).

Comment: :) ah ok, sorry. so for that, set three linearlayouts with orientation horizontal. the linearLayouts have height and width match_parent and layout weight 1. inside the linearLayout set the views also with match_parent and weight=1

Comment: Am using this code with an adapter to make a scrolling sequence of image.http://i59.tinypic.com/fvi7p3.jpg

Hope you understand my problem.
waiting for your reply @Opiatefuchs.

Comment: ok, but this lets the Topic explode here, that´s too much to explain. Refer to this example: http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=92

Answer (score 0):

change this line

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

to:

```
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:scaleType="fitStart"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use weight on LinearLayout.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1.0">

    <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/image"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="0dp"
         android:layout_weight="0.5"
         android:layout_gravity="left|top"
         android:scaleType="centerCrop"
         android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/imaget"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="0dp"
         android:layout_gravity="left|top"
         android:layout_weight="0.5"
         android:scaleType="centerCrop"
         android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```

With setting `android:layout_weight` you can set that images' heights.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to do it. It depends on you which to follow but sometimes it depends on situation. You can handle it from your xml declaring `fill_parent or match_parent`. Also you can handle it using `LinearLayout` and setting it's child `weight`.

Or you can dynamically handle the situation. Suppose that you have a button and you want to put it in the middle  of the screen. In that situation you have to calculate the width and height of the screen dynamically and divide height and width by 2. And then set the calculated width and height to the button.